# Assigning a value to ComboBox Items

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, combobox

I'm currently trying to make a drop box (Combobox) for currencies for a winform. Here's what I have so far:

[image: Screen grab of combobox input]

But I noticed that there is a special option for the Databound version of a drop down box. So I was wondering if it was possible to create something similar to this without resorting to do a comparison against the entire string or creating a table in a database.

[image: Screen shot of combobox tasks]

Comment: A `List(Of T)` will work as a DataSource; If there are objects in the list, you can show one thing (DisplayMember) and evaluate another (ValueMember)

Comment: Any how to get to get to this work, am I adding a list with two dimmensions?

Comment: Better to use a list where the type in the list has two properties you can set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List and Comboboxes can contain objects rather than simply strings.  Rather than defining the contents in the Designer, you can set a `List(Of T)` (among others) as the `DataSource`.  This allows you to display one thing but fetch a different thing such as a value back.

This is so useful, it is not uncommon to have a simple `NameValuePair` class to translate a value or code into something user-friendly:

```
Public Class NVP
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Value As Integer

    Public Sub New(n As String, v As Integer)
        Name = n
        Value = v
    End Sub

    ' what these will display using .ToString:
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0} ({1})", Name, Value.ToString)
    End Function
End Class
```

Then the code to create a list of these and use it as the source for the combo:

```
Private myAList As List(Of NVP)
...
myAList = New List(Of NVP)

myAList.Add(New NVP("ziggy", 26))
myAList.Add(New NVP("able", 1))
myAList.Add(New NVP("charlie", 3))
myAList.Add(New NVP("echo", 5))

ComboBox1.DataSource = myAList
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"    ' property name to show the user
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Value"     ' property name to use as the value
```

Then, using it:

```
Console.WriteLine("Selection Changed! Item: {0}  Value: {1}",
                   ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString,
                   ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString)
```

Output:

> Selection Changed! Item: ziggy (26)  Value: 26
>   Selection Changed! Item: charlie (3)  Value: 3
>   Selection Changed! Item: able (1)  Value: 1

**Notes:**
The benefit to the NameValuePair class is that it keep the data together (and easily accessed) rather then as separate items in different arrays.

The major benefit to using a `DataSource`, is that you do not need to make a copy of the data.  Rather than copy the `Name` values from the list to the `Items` collection, the `List/ComboBox` uses the *same ones* that your code does.

`SelectedItem` returns an `NVP` object (as does `.Items(n)`) but they are returned as `Object` so you need to cast it back to `NameValuePair` to access any properties:

```
thisItem = CType(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, NVP)
Console.WriteLine(thisItem.Name)
```

`SelectedItem.ToString` invokes the `ToString` method on our Type.  It might  simply print the `Name` or whatever you want.

If the *list* is dynamic - things get added and/or removed from it - then you will probably want to use a `BiningList(of T)` instead.  Changes to the **list** will automatically appear in the control (`ListBox`, `ComboBox`, `DatagridView`).

If the list **items** are dynamic - {"ziggy", 26} might be changed to {"zulu", 98}, then your item class should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so those changes also automatically show in the UI control.

Comment: I'm having a slight problem with this one now. I'm trying to a comparison with the `SelectedItem` value but I have no way to access it directly. I tried to use the `.SelectedValue` method but can't seem to find a way that doesn't result in a `InvalidCastException`. Any ideas?

EDIT: Nevermind I just got it. I needed to use thisItem.value after using `CType(combobox1.SelectedItem, NVP)`