# Auto change the SizeMode property from a PictureBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, picturebox

I have a list with these words { AutoSize,Normal,StretchImage,CenterImage,Zoom }

Firstly my users will select one item from the list and after i need to change the property SizeMode of my picture box as their selection.

Can i make something without use of if/switch-case statements ?

```
If (size_mode_list.SelectedText = "AutoSize") Then
    picture_box.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
ElseIf (size_mode_list.SelectedText = "Normal") Then
    picture_box.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal
ElseIf (size_mode_list.SelectedText = "StretchImage") Then
    picture_box.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
ElseIf (size_mode_list.SelectedText = "CenterImage") Then
    picture_box.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
ElseIf (size_mode_list.SelectedText = "Zoom") Then
    picture_box.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Can i make something without use of if/switch-case statements`

One way is to fill the CBO with the Enum names:

```
cbo.Items.AddRange([Enum].GetNames(GetType(PictureBoxSizeMode)))
```

Then parse the result:

```
pb.SizeMode = CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(PictureBoxSizeMode), cbo.Text), 
        PictureBoxSizeMode)
```

Use `.Text` or `SelectedItem.ToString()` and the cbo should be a DropDownList so the user cant type something in.

You could also write a small [Name-ValuePair class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31811533/1070452) to store the Name and Values to a List, then use the `ValueMember` property to set the size mode so you are working off the Enum Value rather than the Name.

Comment: Also i didnt see my results without set the Image path again. I tryed to use the PictureBox.refresh() , but nothing.

Comment: It may depend on how you are setting the image....it works for me.  Probably should ask a new question with those details.