# Validating a group box with 3 radio buttons

Tags: vb.net

I am getting the msgbox whether one of the boxes are selected or not.  Please if anyone has an idea. I would be very thankful

```
Private Function ValidateDiscountSelected(ByRef blnDiscount As Boolean,
     ByRef strDiscount As String) As Integer

    '   This function confirms the user selected a discount available.
    Dim intDiscountSelected As Integer
    Try
        intDiscountSelected = Convert.ToInt32(grpDiscount.Controls)
        strDiscount = grpDiscount.Controls.ToString()
        blnDiscount = True
    Catch exception As SystemException
        '   Confirms a radio button was selected.
        MsgBox("Please Select If Discount Is Available", , "You must Choose A Discount If Avaiable")
        blnDiscount = False
    End Try
    Return intDiscountSelected
```

Comment: What does the debugger show you when you step through the code starting with `intDiscountSelected =`? Or if you comment out the `try catch` and let the exception be raised? What does the exception message tell you?

Comment: `grpDiscount.Controls` a controls collection is never going to be able to be converted to Int32

Comment: hey all thank you for the response.  when I run the debugger I am getting the message box stating that a discount has not been selected.

Comment: That is not an error message - it is your message.  The exception will always be thrown because a controls collection (`grpDiscount.Controls`) cannot be converted to an integer, so an exception is always thrown.

Comment: I think you are right that the problem might be with grpDiscount.Controls.  I have tried almost everything in intelisence and nothing is validating if a radio button has been selected.  I hate to change everything and go to a lstbox.  I am really lost with this one,

Comment: How did you get on with the answers below, Miranda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things which can be improved in that code.  First and foremost:

```
Convert.ToInt32(grpDiscount.Controls)
```

That code tries to convert an entire controls collection to an integer, which cannot ever work.  As a result, the Exception is always thrown.

You apparently want to know which control is checked, but that alone will not tell you the Discount level desired: a control which says "2% Discount" is not the same a `2`.  A UI Control will tell you what the user wants, but you need some way to convert that back into something like a number.

**Determine checked RB**

```
Dim rb = GroupBox3.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton).
                       FirstOrDefault(Function(w) w.Checked)
```

This will tell you which, if any, control is checked.  If each control had the discount stored in the `.Tag` property (e.g. the "10% Discount" control had `10`), you could get the amount back from the Checked one:

```
    If rb IsNot Nothing Then
        ' determine discount amount
        DiscountLevel = Convert.ToInt32(rb.Tag)
    End If

    Return DiscountLevel
```

If none are selected, then `rb` will be `Nothing`.  That ought not ever happen - a group of `RadioButtons` should provide for a default.

**Loop version**

```
    Dim DiscountLevel As Int32 = -1
    For Each rbtn As RadioButton In GroupBox3.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)()
        If rbtn.Checked Then
            DiscountLevel = Convert.ToInt32(rb.Tag)
        End If
    Next
```

At the end, if one is checked, `DiscountLevel` will be >-1.

**Exceptions**

Exceptions are for exceptional situations, not flow control or data validation.  Your code is actually chastising the user when your code fails.  *That* code is not so complex or error prone that it needs a Try/Catch.

**ComboBox**

A `ComboBox` could do the same thing as a group of `RadioButtons`, but do so better and take less space.  You could populate it with `DiscountLevel` objects, where the text says "10%" or whatever, while returning a numeric value to your code.

[Basic class to keep a name/text and value together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31811533/1070452).  This will display the name/text to the user, but return a value to your code.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to leave this as a comment for comparison's sake, but I can't comment yet.  For a selection between only 3 radiobuttons another alternative would be a simple If-ElseIf statement.

```
Dim intDiscountSelected As Integer = 0

If radioButton1.Checked = True Then
    intDiscountSelected = 1
    blnDiscount = True
ElseIf radioButton2.Checked = True Then
    intDiscountSelected = 2
    blnDiscount = True
ElseIf radioButton3.Checked = True
    intDiscountSelected = 3
    blnDiscount = True
End If

If intDiscountSelected = 0 Then
    MsgBox("Please Select If Discount Is Available", , "You must Choose A Discount If Available")
    blnDiscount = False
End If
```

That said, Plutonix's loop version is a more concise option that scales better.