# Update bindingSource used for combobox

Tags: .net, vb.net, binding

For a long time now I have been trying to fix a problem with a combobox (it givs me headaches when I think at how many tests and forums I've tried). I know that after a combobox has been "binded" to a source it will be synchronised with it(every change will appear in combobox).

Here's my simple testing code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim a As New BindingSource, b As New Hashtable


    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ComboBox1.DataSource = a
        ComboBox2.DataSource = a


        b.Add(1, "a")
        b.Add(2, "b")


        a.DataSource = b
        a.DataMember = "Value"



        '' Tried this when a.DataMember is commented .Otherwise it gives error
        ''ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value"
        ''ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Key"
        ''ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "Value"
        ''ComboBox2.ValueMember = "Key"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        b.Add(3, "c")  ''Nothing new in the combobox
        ''a.ResetBindings(False)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**This is how it looks:**

[image]

When I de-comment the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties of the comboboxes this is what happens(and after pressing Button1):

[image]

As you can see the count property says there are 2 items but the DataSource says there are 3. I think that's why the new-added item doesn't appear (when I press Button1 the new element is not being added despite the fact it is stored in the BindingSource).

Where is the problem?

**Note:** I found something maybe useful on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c12c1kx4.aspx) but it's not quite working (I updated the code according to this page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I know that after a combobox has been "binded" to a source it will be synchronised with it(every change will appear in combobox).`

The problem is that your understanding is not entirely true. You need to use a special collection for changes to the contents to automatically show up in the control.  If the contents of the collection is a Type (Class), changes to one of the properties will not automatically show up without another step.

The ham-fisted way to overcome this is to "reset" the `DataSource`:

```
cbox.DataSource = Nothing
ht.Add(0, "Zulu")
cbox.DataSource = New BindingSource(ht, Nothing)
cbox.DisplayMember = "Value"
cbox.ValueMember = "Key"
```

This rebuilds the `BindingSource` (or builds a new one in this case) so it can "see" the new entry.  The `Display-` and `ValueMember` values are lost, so you have to reset those.  "Resetting" can also cause problems with something like a `ListBox` because any previous selections will be lost.

There is a way built into the `BindingSource` which does the opposite depending on the underlying collection:

```
cboBS.Add(New DictionaryEntry(0, "Zulu"))
```

- `cboBS` is the `BindingSource` for the Combo
- `DictionaryEntry` is the Type which holds each entry in a `HashTable`.

Now, the new entry shows up and is in the `BindingSource`, but it is not in your underlying `HashTable`. The new item will get added to something like a `List<T>` (a `HashSet<T>` would be a better choice than `HashTable`).

---

**The problem with most collections is that they do not signal when and item is added or deleted.**  Most collections are like this and the `BindingSource` can't solve it.

Your best bet may be to use a `BindingList(Of T)`. (This wont enforce the unique key constraint if the `HashTable`, just check to see if the value has been added - you need to do that anyway with a `HashTable` to avoid Exceptions.)  Another thing which will work - but may seem odd - is a `DataTable`.

```
Private BList As BindingList(Of NameValuePair)
...
BList = New BindingList(Of NameValuePair)
BList.Add(New NameValuePair("Alpha", 1))
BList.Add(New NameValuePair("Delta", 4))
BList.Add(New NameValuePair("Gamma", 3))
BList.Add(New NameValuePair("Beta", 2))
cbox.DataSource = BList
cbox.DisplayMember = "Name"
cbox.ValueMember = "Value"
```

You no longer need a `BindingSource`.  `NameValuePair` is a simple utility class [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31811533/1070452) to associate a `Value` with a 'Name'.  You could also use a `KeyValuePair(Of TK, TV)`.

Adding am item to the list, requires no extra step and no rebinding.  It automatically shows.  However, if you change a property on an item in the list:

```
myPersonList(0).Name = "Ziggy"
```

...these changes will *not* show up unless the underlying class implements `INotifyPropertyChange`.

The link above approaches the question differently: [Assigning a value to ComboBox Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31811533) and may also be helpful.

The [blog entry listed in the comment](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dchandnani/2005/03/15/bindingsource-a-closer-look/) is pretty good too.  It also covers a bit about other collections and use cases with some info in the Whys and Wherefores.

Comment: Blog at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dchandnani/2005/03/15/bindingsource-a-closer-look/ led me to a similar solution. Your's is much more in depth than what I would have written though. +1